# Handling Switch Control Event in Listview for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I want to add a listener of some sort to the Toggle button I am using in this code. Since there are multiple togglebuttons(one per listview item) then the listener should specify perhaps what row it related to. I cannot really find a nice way to do this in xaml. Can anyone here help perhaps? I though about referring to the list by x:Name, access it in code and try to reach the toggle by type casting, then adding a listener on the button. That is quite tricky. Any advice on how to solve this? Btw: Names are just a,b,c,d just to hide details regarding my customer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:me="clr-namespace:simpletest;assemby=simpletest" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="simpletest.WeekView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="8,10">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding a}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Text="{Binding b}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            </StackLayout>
            <me:HideableListView ItemsSource="{Binding c}" SeparatorVisibility="Default">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding d}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                    <Label Text="{Binding e}" FontSize="Small" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding f}" Toggled="{Binding g}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </me:HideableListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the `Switch` control with an extra property like `MyItem` and bind it with your source like

```
<ExtendedSwitch IsToggled="{Binding f}"
 MyItem={Binding e} Toggled="{Binding OnItemToggled}"  />
```

The extended Switch

```
public class ExtendedSwitch: Switch
    {
        public object MyItem { get; set; }
    }
```

The ToggledEvent

```
public void OnItemToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            var toggledSwitch = (ExtendedSwitch)sender;
            var item = toggledSwitch.MyItem;
        }
```